# "ON UPDATE" in self referencing table

Tags: postgresql, update, foreign-key, recursive, cascade

I have a table **Category** with a **parent_id** column referencing the self **id** column, for this, I used "ON DELETE CASCADE" meaning if the parent is deleted, other children would be deleted too.

At the same table I have a boolean column **active**, is it possible to use **ON UPDATE CASCADE** in order to make the update of this column impact recursively all the children of the updated row?

let's take this example **parent > sub1 > sub2**, what is the way (at the database level) to make the update of the column **active** impact all the children?

- update the **parent** will impact himself and **sub1** and **sub2**
- update the **sub1** will impact himself and the **sub2**.

and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Postgres so can't go into specifics but it looks like you'd be ab;e to achieve your aims by using a trigger that fires on update of the Active column.
Set the function to check for any child records and update any found. The trigger should recurse through all levels until it finds a record with no children.
[Postgres Trigger Functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I really want to avoid the trigger method. It will be nice if the update can be cast automatically one by one like the delete is.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an inbuilt method of cascading "soft deletes". If you don't want to use triggers, I try to avoid them, too, you're probably stuck with having to handle these updates in a stored procedure that checks for child records on update or handling it in application code.